# Spark submit works well with 1 executor and 1 driver, but fails with multiple executor

Tags: java, apache-spark, weka, emr, porter-stemmer

I am running one application on yarn-cluster mode.
My application is doing following inside map operation.

1. load weka model from S3 to java object
2. predict record using loaded weka model object

The problem is this is running well with 1 executor, not with multiple executors.

Here is the error which i am getting

> Stemmer 'porter' unknown!
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at weka.core.stemmers.SnowballStemmer.stem(SnowballStemmer.java:408)
>       at cat.weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.SmtStringToWordVector.convertInstancewoDocNorm(TestStringToWordVector.java:1768)
>       at cat.weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.SmtStringToWordVector.input(TestSmtStringToWordVector.java:776)
>       at cat.engine.prediction.WekaMLPredictor.convertStringToWordVector(WekaMLPredictor.java:203)

Here is my scala code used inside map operation

```
def applyMLModel(row: Row) {
val wekamodel = getmodel(id)
var result = wekamodel.predict(attr)
}
```

Comment: Are you just changing the number of executors using `--num-executors` option in `spark-submit`? Is that the only thing you are changing?

Comment: This [blog post](https://markahall.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/weka-and-spark.html) from last year suggests that only yarn-client mode is supported for weka, not yarn-cluster - could this be your problem?